# How to do a global from foo import bar from a method in python?

Tags: python

So I'm working on implementing a websocket client protocol on a robot called NAO. Without going into too many details, I can't do a normal import because a variable is needed before I can do any import statements, so I need to handle my import statements in a method.

Problem is is that I need these packages across multiple classes in a single file, and therefore I REALLY need to make these imports global.

Now I found another StackOverflow post handling pretty much the same thing:

[Python: how to make global imports from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990556/python-how-to-make-global-imports-from-a-function)

However, this post only handles regular imports, not class imports (there is probably a correct name for this, but I don't know it)

Does anybody have an idea on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
>>> def f():
...     global pi
...     from math import pi
...
>>> pi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pi' is not defined
>>> f()
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
>>>
```

Comment: Well, I tried this before, but I wasn't sure that this was the correct approach, so I abandoned it when I received a different error.

But your answer has given me some insight into this new error. It seems that importing from a method causes classes that have an imported superclass to throw an error. This behaviour can be replicated on desktop as well.

I realise this is a totally different question, but I might as well ask:
Do you know any way around this?

Comment: @user2983738 hm maybe I could help but I'd need some more details. Maybe just make a new question on SO? It's hard to debug code without seeing it :)